# Is there a way to reference/index/pointer an item in a std::stack?

Tags: c++, assembly, stack, virtual-machine

As the title says, using std::stack is there a way to reference any item by reference/index/pointer without popping? If not how could I achieve this?

My use case is, I am making a vm for learning and I want to reference the stack items in the std::stack so I can push and access my local stack variables. I originally was going to just make a stack implementation - but I have the stl! I am guessing I may have to roll my own because the items are immutable, and I haven't seen any docs stating it :(

My use case (asm ; c++)

```
mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 123  ; stack.push(123);
mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 321  ; stack.push(321);
add DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1    ; stack[?] = stack[?] + 1;
```

Comment: No the STL stack only has a peek at the front. But you can easily mimick a stack using std::vector for yourself that allows you to inspect all values (push_back and pop_back are implemented on std::vector)

Comment: thanks, I will try that - it will be a lot better than rolling my own.

Comment: Do you mean `std::stack` instead of `stl::stack`? Otherwise, what are you referring to? `std::stack` is just a small wrapper around some other container like `std::vector` or `std::deque`. If you need more than the stack interface, then use these containers directly.

Comment: I meant std::stack. I didn't know I could use the underlying containers though.

Comment: `mov` stores aren't push operations; they don't move the stack pointer.  That would be more like `vec[framepointer + 1]` or whatever, with stack pointer movement at the start of a function being like `vec.resize(vec.size() + 6)` or something.  But the asm stack can be addressed as bytes, words, dwords, qwords, or whatever, while C++ containers have a fixed element type, not a bag of raw bytes.  (In my earlier examples, I was assuming a `std::vector<uint32_t>`, so 4-byte offsets in asm are 1-element offsets in the vector.  And it grows upward, not downward, so I negated the offsets.)

Comment: `std::stack` is a wrapper around `deque` or `vector`, to use when you **only** want push and pop without the risk of (accidentally) fiddling with the other elements. If you *do* want access to everything, just use `deque` or `vector` instead.

Comment: You can construct a stack using an existing container. Do that with a vector

Comment: @ArminMontigny Yes that surely is a way :) However in the end you still iterate over a std::vector used as underlying container. But it is an easy way to hide all vector operations and only show the stack ones. So yes, nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way to access the data through its underlying container.

Normally, all this is not necessary because you always can use the underlying container in the first place.

But if you want to do that for exceptional purposes, then simply take the address of the `top()`. This will be the last element in the underlying container. And if you subtract the `size()` of the stack (corrected by 1), then you have a pointer to the beginning of the underlying container.

And then you can use the subscript operator `[]` as expected.

Please see the following example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using Number = int;
using UnderlyingContainer = std::vector<Number>;
using Stack = std::stack< Number, UnderlyingContainer>;

using StackIterator = Number *const;

int main()
{
    // Put the test data onto the stack
    Stack myStack{ UnderlyingContainer {1,2,3,4,5} };

    if (not myStack.empty()) {

        // Get "iterators"
        StackIterator end = &myStack.top() + 1;
        StackIterator begin = end - myStack.size();

        Number *const & stk = begin;

        for (size_t i{}; i < myStack.size(); ++i)
            stk[i] = stk[i] + 10;

        for (size_t i{}; i < myStack.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << stk[i] << '\n';

        std::transform(begin, end, begin, [](const Number n) {return n - 10; });
        std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<Number>(std::cout, "\n"));
    }
}
```

So, it looks like we found what you want to have, but in reality, we simply work on the underlying container.

But as said, there are sometimes reasons to do so . . .